# PHP open link in iframe

Tags: php, html, url, iframe

I have the following code presently:

```
if(isset($_POST['Movie']))
{
    $check = $_POST['Movie'];
    echo "(left angle bracket)a target='imdb' href='http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&source=hp&fkt=3948&fsdt=45174&q=$check imdb&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&meta=&aq=f&oq='>IMDB PREVIEW";

}
```

This gives me a link to click which when I do click opens in an iframe called imdb.
How do I cut out the middle man (having to click the link) and just have this link open directly in the iframe.

I already have an iframe named imdb and I want to display the link in there.

**What I ended up doing was just to echo a new iframe with the same class as the other iframe so that the end user will not know that they are different iframes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not include the source for the iframe itself, but basically, all you have to do is echo the URL into the iframe's src attribute:

```
echo '<iframe id="imdb" src="'.'http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&source=hp&fkt=3948&fsdt=45174&q=$check imdb&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&meta=&aq=f&oq="></iframe>';
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I understood your question, but maybe you want to do this:

```
echo '<iframe src="http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&source=hp&fkt=3948&fsdt=45174&q=$check imdb&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&meta=&aq=f&oq=" />';
```